# ANT: Foreach not excluding files when target attrbute is used

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have a foreach tag to execute all the files within a particular directory. As part of the fileset I have excluded two files.

But irrespective of excluding the files, the param still passes the two files to the target "runpART"

I do not want to call the target for the excluded files.

Let me know if there is any way to do it. The following does not seem to work

```
    <foreach target="runART" param="p.schedulerFile" inheritall="true" inheritrefs="true">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${p.dir}" casesensitive="no">
                <!--<include name="**\*.xml"/>-->
                <excludesfile name="${pART.dir}\CodeCoverage_NSR.xml"/>
                <excludesfile name="${pART.dir}\CodeCoverageRegression_HLR.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </path> 
    </foreach>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want <excludesfile >, which expects a file containing exclude patterns, you want

```
 <exclude name="CodeCoverage_NSR.xml">
 <exclude name="CodeCoverageRegression_HLR.xml">
```

Now, that's assuming you meant to have ${p.dir} == ${pART.dir}.
Exclude patterns in a fileset have to be relative to the root dir of the fileset (here, its dir="${p.dir}").
For more info, see: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html

Comment: Thank you.. this works... This link does not have <exclude> tag http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html

Comment: Glad it helped you. The link does show you some <exclude> tags in the examples section, in the second half of the page. Also, it links to the documentation on patternset's (at: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html); filesets support an implied patternset which translates to: you can use <include > and <exclude > child tags.